# Named variable or remote connection?

Tags: geometry-nodes

In some graph-based systems it's possible to have a "remote" connection between nodes to reduce spaghetti. In other words, the output from one node goes into a named pin. If you then have an identically-named pin somewhere else in the graph, those two pins will be internally connected. Think EDA or PCB design software.

Reroute nodes help, but sometimes I calculate a value near the start of the graph and then need it at various points along the graph, and it's very messy and confusing to have one very long wire going all the way along the graph. It's easy to forget what value the wire represents. As a programmer, I'd love to be able to just pipe a value into a named variable and then reuse that variable whenever needed.

Is it possible to do this in geometry nodes?

I've looked at named attributes but I don't think this is the intended usage for them. Named attributes store values alongside geometry, but what I'm looking for would just be syntactic sugar and exactly equivalent to dragging a wire between two nodes.

Comment: There are no "remote" connections between nodes. But you can create nested node groups, and you can add multiple group input nodes to create "shortcuts" of inputs. Not sure if that helps you.

Comment: @Blunder I use nested node groups frequently. Multiple copies of the Group Input node (along with Ctrl+H) is my best friend. But sometimes that just isn't a good solution. I was really just hoping for named sockets :( The internal implementation would also be incredibly simple: just don't draw the wires between named sockets (or I guess it would be more like named Reroute nodes).

Comment: This feature has been discussed for several years. Progress unknown. https://devtalk.blender.org/t/portal-links-exploration/21306

Comment: @quellenform Ah, thanks. If you convert your comment to an answer I'll accept it.